# Moderator seeks testers for short private beta of Clean Up Week

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Well after a *very* long time, I think I have the website for the [Clean Up Week](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1220/clean-up-week-event-planning) ready. It's taken so long because I've had to refactor the plans several times over due to technical restrictions on what we can handle.

The plan is still to have a week-long competition where people can chow through as many old threads as possible. I'm just waiting on Stack Exchange to get back to me on what we can offer up as prizes.

#### But right now, I need to make sure this works!

I'm looking for 10-20 people who have some time on Saturday. Preferably people who have had experience reviewing questions/answers, people who are good at posting answers, leaving helpful comments, flagging, voting to close things, etc. I also hope people will be good at submitting bugs and suggestions to make the whole thing better.

As such there is a minimum reputation for the demo. For the demo, I'd like users with at least 3000 reputation. I know that's quite high but I'd like people who can do everything needed (edit/close/comment/etc) on this first run.

There won't be any limits on the real thing.

If you're interested just send an email to **oli@thepcspy.com** with a link to your profile (yes, I'm lazy) and I'll reply within 24 hours with a web address and some basic instructions.

Comment: *Reads post... Immediately sends email...*

Comment: Oh, and +1 for prizes.

Comment: Count me in. Got my bleach, disinfecting material, sponge, gloves and a pack of gum. I have come here to chew bubble gum and clean up... and i'm all out of gum.

Comment: How close to being "ready" is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testing is done and the software has been used for some time now. See  [Ask Ubuntu Clean Up](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2651/ask-ubuntu-clean-up) for the public release.