# Why is hiding GRUB menu too localized?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

As per my brother's request, I want to hide the GRUB menu, on his dual-boot machine, only to have it appear when he presses some key. I Googled and found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70875/hide-grub-menu-and-keystroke-to-reveal), and a few days later I noticed it was closed.

Why? What makes hiding GRUB too localized? How is it a knowledge that will not benefit others? I request it to be reopened.

On an unrelated note, I wish there's something like the Launchpad feature of 'me too' on SE, that will allow inputs from others to the question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now reopened. I apologize for closing it, it appeared to be abandoned and without answer.

Answer (score 5):

That question was closed in an effort to weed out our abandoned questions. It is not too localized for the site.

Apparently it is a false positive. I have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

The last comment for that question reads

> This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you
>   perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a
>   similar issue please ask a new question with details pertaining to
>   your problem. If you feel this question is not abandoned, then please
>   flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any
>   details you have).

See also [Closing abandoned questions is harder than it should be.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2329/closing-abandoned-questions-is-harder-than-it-should-be)

Instead of 'me too' you could vote for the question if it is well written or add comments with more info so that it gets a higher chance of getting answered.

Answer (score 2):

As one of the five people who voted on the question in discussion to be closed, I think it is only appropriate that you hear from one of us.

So, well, as Octavian Damien pointed out, our intentions were merely to keep the site clear of abandoned questions and not to limit sharing of knowledge.

On saying that, I have cast my reopen vote on the question. You should hopefully get it opened sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 2):

Its is not that the question was too localized, it was simply closed because there was no input of activity from the OP for a long time and such question can be closed after some time using *too localized* as the main reason.

If you look at the user page from the OP you can see that the user has only that question, no answers or further activity on the site since October. I would agree that flagging a question with less then 3 months as abandoned has a great risk of not being valid, but in this case I would say it is safe to do so. There is a big change the user will not come back (last login was almost 4 months ago) so flag it, close it.

In case a user feels that his question was flagged unfairly and he wants to open the question again he can always flag a moderator to open it or if a new user would like to ask the same question with intentions of getting an answer and responding to comments that user can simply create a new one. New question that have activity cannot be flagged as dupes of something that is closed.

In the end we closed a question that probably would be lost and without answers for a very long time and we create opportunity for a user to ask that same question without the risk of having it closed as dupe.