# List of questions with votes to close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

There are a number of old buried questions which I have voted to close as duplicates, too localized, etc... Most of them, I'm the only vote so far. I imagine that there are many other open questions that should be closed that are hanging around with one or two close votes. How can I find them in order to kill them? Is there a list of questions with votes to close?

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2329/closing-abandoned-questions-is-harder-than-it-should-be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [list here](https://askubuntu.com/review/close?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=all&no-random=1) but I think it's part of the 10k rep tools.

Comment: It is part of the 10K tools.

Answer (score 5):

We also now have: https://askubuntu.com/review-beta/close