# Wrong flag on question

Tags: support, flagging

This question has been flagged as "too localized"

[Unity does not run .xsession/.Xsession/.xsessionrc/.xinitrc on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83858/ubuntu-11-10-with-unity-does-not-run-xsession-xsession-xsessionrc-xinitrc-on)

this is clearly wrong, just look at all the other questions talking about xinitrc:
https://askubuntu.com/search?q=xinitrc

Answer (score 3):

That action is part of the [Ask Ubuntu Clean Up](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2651/ask-ubuntu-clean-up) in progress since a month ago.

Questions that have no answers, no activity and no comments for a long time are being closed as *Abandoned* with the recommendation of improving the details in it, flagging the question's closure has invalid (will probably trigger an bounty from one of the mods to create attention to it) or to simply re-create the question again.

This is a fair issue since question that have no answers might prevent a user from creating them once visiting the site. Closing those creates the opportunity and draws attention to them, increasing the chances that answers will be posted and a valid solution will be presented to the issue.

Since mods do not have a "Abandoned" reason for closure a comment is created on the question and this one is closed as "Too localized".

Sometimes it does not fit perfectly the conditions but seems to be the most appropriate course of action.

Note that a question closed will remain in the site and a user can **always** flag and talk to a moderator to re-open it.

Comment: This is unsatisfying... :(
besides the fact that I can't flag the question (apparently 15 reputation is needed)

reusing the same question, editing it if necessary, and adding an answer is clearly a better approach to closing and reopening (unless the question went horribly out of date, but this is not the case)

Comment: @berdario Yeah, but now you have the chance of creating of picking up the question yourself, creating a new one with more information and getting answers on it instead of being forever lost till the end of times. About the rep, I fixed that just now (you have to admit, 15 rep is not hard to get at all!), now you have the option of flagging the post for re-opening -explain that you have a similar issue and you would like see it answered- or just create a similar question by your self. I know its not perfect, but then again, nothing will be.