# Review Old Questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, review, old-questions

How do we deal with really old questions that don't have an accepted answer or no answer at all?  I know that the 'Community User' bumps them once in a while, but is that enough?  Our answered ratio is just awful, fourth worst in the network, and I think if we had a review queue or something similar for old questions we might get more of them answered/flagged/closed.

What do you think?

Comment: we have an unofficial one that Oli made - http://cleanup.thepcspy.com, it does the general thing that you're looking for.

Comment: @jrg I know, but how effective is that?

Comment: it's fairly effective, and ping Oli in chat about it. He might have details on how to fix it.

Comment: It's not effective for those who use Facebook Connect.

Comment: @Mochan you can use your stack exchange ID, except right now its broken because of API changes.

Comment: How would I get my Stack Exchange ID?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2651/44179) post by Oli.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've assembled a wide range of data queries that can be used to pick out questions in need of attention.

- [Questions who have at least 1 answer with no answers exceeding more than 2 votes and no accepted answer.](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/37462/unaccepted-questions)
- [Possible open bug reports](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/82555/possibly-open-bug-reports)
- [Low quality unanswered questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/36927/low-quality-unanswered-questions)
- [Kill ALL abandoned questions WITH FIRE](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/48626/kill-all-abandoned-questions)
- [Show stupid posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/60951/show-stupid-posts-freeze-crash-bug)
- [Find high scoring posts with out of date Software Links](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/58132/find-high-scoring-out-of-date-software-links)
- [Questions whos answers don't have any screenshots but have a very high view count](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/40360/high-view-counts-with-no-images)
- [Low quality unanswered posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/36926/low-quality-unanswered-posts)

Each of these queries vary from posts that need help with editing, that need to be closed, that need to be voted on, or that just need answers.

Comment: @iSeth You can start going through these and voting to closed the abandoned ones, it will at least get them in the close queue. It's tough though, I find I run out of votes very quickly. :-/

Comment: @JorgeCastro I don't have 3k rep yet :(  But maybe I could flag them as something?  40 a day isn't much I know..

Comment: flags are fine too!

Comment: @JorgeCastro What should I flag them as?

Comment: They'll either be too localized if they're abandoned or offtopic if it's really a bug.