# Do we need a vacuum cleaner? (corvee week?)

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[image]

Related to [this one](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11592/how-can-we-encourage-3k-users-to-review-more-close-votes) and even more to [this one](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13519/why-do-you-not-review/13526#13526), and probably a lot more; Do we need a "clean up week" to get rid of the depressing load of posts, waiting to be reviewed (without forgetting to be mindful of course)? Like don.joey mentions in one of his answers, a longer list becomes less "inviting". It wasn't my hobby to start with.

I think a too large stock is not a good thing; posts that need to be put on hold need to be put on hold. Too much time between the first close vote and the final result is holding the procedure/poluting the process.

Today will be rather busy, but I'll try to do my share from tomorrow...

Comment: The mods already planned such a clean-up week about 4 years ago. (See [this post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1220/367990)) I wonder whether the event has happened or whether they did not achieve any more than planning, as I joined only about six weeks ago. But I appreciate the idea, so +1.

Comment: As you can read [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2863/367990), the cleanup week took place in March/April 2012. I just found out. They also set up some kind of extra cleanup-tool for all users described [there](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2651/367990). I will try that out...

Comment: @ByteCommander AHA, That was indeed "before my time" as well. I do remember Alvarado in a review- delirium (or he must have been).

Comment: Anyone knows how to find out my Open-ID? I need it for logging into that cleanup-tool... :-(

Comment: @ByteCommander what do you use to login? Your Google account?

Comment: I can only review 20-40 per day and that's what I do daily...  Once every two days it's my favourite subject: duplicates (so fun!), and the other days the system decides (work!)

Comment: @muru No, I only have a StackExchange account for AU and some other ?.SE sites.

Answer (score 7):

I've been playing janitor on close votes ever since I broke 3k. Even attacking the close queue every day I can't make a dent. Perhaps boosting the number that can be reviewed in a day would help? During the past week I've seen the number climb from the high nine's to the current 1k+. Due in part to the large number of flagged poor questions the heap is huge. If we don't all do all we can every day we will get buried in the refuse.

As I see it our options are as follows (in no particular order):

A) **Get a working question wizard** to help reduce the incoming trash.

B) **Increase the reviewing max.** I'm not sure if the number was decided on by consensus with other SE sites but it's not logical to limit those who are actually willing to do the work at the time they are willing to do it. Furthermore AU is a magnet for every inexperienced user who ever installed Ubuntu (which IMHO is the most popular Linux Distro of all time) which makes it somewhat unique when compared to the other stackexchange sites. The rules need to be adjusted to accommodate this.

C) **Increase staffing.** As a volunteer myself, I don't see how this can be accomplished other than being friendly to those asking the questions in the hope that eventually they too will decide to help.

D) **All of the above!**

Comment: Rant over. I'm back to work on the close queue. Why aren't you?

Comment: Ok, booted from close queue again...

Comment: "Perhaps boosting the number that can be reviewed in a day would help?" Unlikely. What will happen is that the question gets another mark but you still need others to also mark it. Let's say you and 3 others review every day you will still see a (gradual) increase if those topics do not get more reviews from others. The best method would be if the amount of reviews for 1 topic is lowered. That would speed things up but I doubt that it is possible with the current setup.

Comment: @Rinzwind I do understand that there needs to be a consensus that a post be closed and also the value of that approach. What I'm looking for is an effective solution that **is** possible. Can't isn't a word that's in my vocabulary...

Answer (score 6):

Luis Alvarado is our resident vacuum cleaner.

<sub>Upvote if you agree or are Luis Alvarado, downvote if you do not agree :)</sub>

<sub>I'll will max my reviewing for today soon</sub>

Related: [How can we encourage 3k+ users to review more Close Votes](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11592/how-can-we-encourage-3k-users-to-review-more-close-votes)

Comment: Haha, That's a good one! Poor Alvarado...